# How to start powershell with a specific window size from RUN?

Tags: windows, powershell

How to start a powershell from "RUN" with specific window size? is there any argument for that like "-size:100x100". is that possible with RUN or is there any other way to run a program window with a given size?

Comment: `PowerShell.exe -noe -c ". mode.com con: lines=25 cols=80"`

Comment: I suggest you play around with the properties you see with `$host.ui.rawui|gm`

Comment: @JosefZ: That works in principle, but the unfortunate side effect is that you lose any scroll-back buffer (the buffer height is set to the window height).

Answer (score 40, accepted):

#### From the Windows `Run` dialog:

The following command starts PowerShell in a console window with the default size and *then* resizes the window to 100 columns x 50 rows:

```
powershell -noexit -command "[console]::WindowWidth=100; [console]::WindowHeight=50; [console]::BufferWidth=[console]::WindowWidth"
```

<sup>Note: `powershell -noexit -command "mode con cols=100 lines=50"` works in principle, but has the unfortunate side effect that *you lose any scroll-back buffer* (the buffer height is set to the window height).</sup>

The command uses the `[console]` ([`System.Console`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console)) .NET type to set the window width and height, and additionally sets the *buffer width* to the same value as the *window* width, so as to ensure that no horizontal scroll bar appears.

#### From an existing console window:

If you run the above command from an existing Command Prompt or PowerShell console, the new PowerShell session starts in the *current* window, and therefore resizes the *current* window.
Here's how to  **open a *new* window**:

- from a Command Prompt (`cmd.exe`): use `start`:

  ```
  start powershell -noexit -command "[console]::windowwidth=100; [console]::windowheight=50; [console]::bufferwidth=[console]::windowwidth"
  ```
- from a PowerShell console window: use `Start-Process` (note the single quotes around the argument list):

  ```
  start-process powershell '-noexit -command "[console]::windowwidth=100; [console]::windowheight=50; [console]::bufferwidth=[console]::windowwidth"'
  ```

---

#### If you don't want to resize the window *after* it has opened with the default size:

The commands above run *after* the new window has been created with the default size, which can be visually disruptive.

To prevent that, you have two options:

- **Create a shortcut file** that targets `powershell.exe`, configure its properties to set the desired size, then run the *shortcut file* (`*.lnk`) to open the window.

  - As [papo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3273963/papo) points out, **you can also preset the window size for PowerShell instances you invoke via the Start Menu, via the <kbd>Win-X</kbd> shortcut menu, or via File Explorer's `File > Open Windows Powershell` command** that way, by **modifying the *preexisting* underlying shortcut file**:<sup>[1]</sup>

    ```
    "$env:AppData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Windows PowerShell\Windows PowerShell.lnk"
    ```
- **Change the *default* window size** to your liking, but note that this then applies to *all* PowerShell sessions started with just the executable name (or path):

  - Interactively:

    - Press <kbd>Win+R</kbd> and submit just `powershell`
    - Open the new window's system menu, select `Properties` and configure the window size as desired.
      Future windows launched the same way will have the same size.
  - Programmatically:

    - Console window properties are stored in the registry at `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Console`, with the `REG_DWORD` value `WindowSize` containing the window size, and `ScreenBufferSize` containing the buffer size:
    - Key `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Console` (`HKCU:\Console`) contains the overall defaults.
    - Subkeys, such as `%SystemRoot%_System32_WindowsPowerShell_v1.0_powershell.exe`, contain overrides for specific executables / window titles.

      - **Important**: These settings do *not* apply to console windows started via *shortcut files (`.lnk`)*; the latter *dynamically* inherit the overall console defaults directly from `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Console` (not from any subkeys) - except for `CodePage` on Windows 10 (not sure about Windows 8/8.1), and except for values later overridden via the `Properties` dialog, which are saved *directly in the file*.
    - Subkeys *inherit* values from their parent, which complicates setting values for subkeys - see below for an example.

---

#### Setting `powershell.exe` window-size defaults programmatically:

The following PSv5+ snippet sets the default window size for `powershell.exe`-launched console windows to 100 columns by 50 rows.

Note that the fact that screen *buffer* values are *inherited* from the overall default settings, stored directly in `HKCU:\Console`, adds complexity.

```
# Determine the target registry key path.
$keyPath = 'HKCU:\Console\%SystemRoot%_System32_WindowsPowerShell_v1.0_powershell.exe'

# Get the existing key or create it on demand.
$key = Get-Item $keyPath -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
if (-not $key) { $key = New-Item $keyPath }

# Determine the new size values.
[uint32] $cols = 100; [uint32] $lines = 50
# Convert to a DWORD for writing to the registry.
[uint32] $dwordWinSize = ($cols + ($lines -shl 16))

# Note: Screen *buffer* values are inherited from 
#       HKCU:\Console, and if the inherited buffer width is larger
#       than the window width, the window width is apparently set to 
#       the larger size.
#       Therefore, we must also set the ScreenBufferSize value, passing through
#       its inherited height value while setting its width value to the same
#       value as the window width.
[uint32] $dwordScreenBuf = Get-ItemPropertyValue HKCU:\Console ScreenBufferSize -EA SilentlyContinue
if (-not $dwordScreenBuf) {  # No buffer size to inherit.
  # Height is 3000 lines by default. 
  # Note that if we didn't set this explicitly, the buffer height would 
  # default to the same value as the window height.
  $dwordScreenBuf = 3000 -shl 16  
}

# Set the buffer width (low word) to the same width as the window
# (so that there's no horizontal scrolling).
$dwordScreenBuf = $cols + (($dwordScreenBuf -shr 16) -shl 16)

# Write the new values to the registry.
Set-ItemProperty -Type DWord $key.PSPath WindowSize $dwordWinSize
Set-ItemProperty -Type DWord $key.PSPath ScreenBufferSize $dwordScreenBuf
```

---

<sup>[1] papo further states, "[That the] Win+X Menu actually starts this lnk (will error if missing), which is weird, as Win+X has its own shortcuts: `"$env:LOCALAPPDATA\Microsoft\Windows\WinX\Group3"`, which are ignored. (Win10 1809). PS started from Explorer's > File will still work if this link is removed, but will use *defaults* from registry."</sup>

Comment: Thanks for the very first command, I put this at the top of my profile and now I get the default Powershell Core window size. However do you know how to set the location of the console at the center of the screen? I tried to play with `[console]::WindowLeft` and `[console]::WindowTop` but it seems to change the location of the scrollbars, not the window itself... Thanks

Comment: @JérômeMEVEL Indeed, these properties cannot be used to position a window. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42334329/45375) contains a C# solution. Since a PowerShell-based solution may be of interest too, I encourage you to ask a _new_ question.

Comment: Is there any way to specify that after resizing, lock window size? e.g. preventing users from resizing the window after powershell has been launched?

Comment: @Hatefiend: I don't if that can be done; if it can be done, it won't be trivial. I encourage you to ask a _new_ question that focuses on that.

Comment: Are you aware of any documentation by Microsoft outlining your "Programmatically" section? Issuing the command `start "some title"` will look for `some title` as a subkey to HKCU\Console but I just cannot find this documented anywhere.

Comment: @madeslurpy, I'm afraid I don't have a documentation link; my answer is based on trial and error.

Comment: Okay, I just find articles describing it, but no actual documentation saying how conhost picks the settings from the registry.

Comment: @JérômeMEVEL Did you ask a question on this? Agree with mklement0 that it's a good question to ask. I do have a full PowerShell-based solution for this that I use every time that I open a console that I will post if you can send a link to the question.

Answer (score 3):

Had issues with the rest of my script running in the same resized window.

This seemed to work though:

```
[console]::WindowWidth=80; 
[console]::WindowHeight=50; 
[console]::BufferWidth=[console]::WindowWidth

cd myDirectory
node app
```

Example above is a Powershell script I run to launch my node API

Comment: I'm not understanding what this adds that isn't covered in [mklement0's detailed answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43298114/150605).  You're modifying the same properties of `[Console]` as that answer is except you're doing so in the script itself instead of the command line.  This won't work if there's no script involved, and the question isn't specifically asking about a script, either.