# powershell set window size and execute script with params

Tags: powershell

i'm trying to execute new instances of powershell in a loop and pass in parameters. I am able to do this but the additional arguments for setting the window size seems to break things.

Current working without setting the window size

`start-process powershell -argumentlist "-noexit -file c:\test\script.ps1 -port 12345"`

If I run the below in isolation it works but I can't seem to figure out how to merge this with the above

`powershell -argumentlist "-noexit mode con:cols=72 lines=5"`

I tried the following but that gave an error:

`powershell -argumentlist "-noexit mode con:cols=72 lines=5 -file c:\test\script.ps1 -port 12345"`

`Invalid parameter - -file`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to start powershell with a specific window size from RUN?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43296216/how-to-start-powershell-with-a-specific-window-size-from-run)

Comment: No it doesn't, as I said I can set the window size by itself but the trouble I am having is setting the window size and executing a script with parameters is one command.